# Change Popup background Image with JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JS Function:

```
function zoom(now) {
document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("photos").style.backgroundImage = "url('" +    now + "')";
}
```

And I have echoed  in php, which has onclick function

```
echo 
"<td style='background: url(" . $row['thumbnails'] . ")' onclick='zoom(" . $row['imagelink'] . ")'></td>";
```

So it says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.
```

When I put just 1.jpg in php instead of imagelink it works. but not with $row['imagelink']. I absolutely need to change background image, so please if anyone can help or give me a different option in JS, PHP, HTML only. Thank you

Comment: BTW, proper html should use double quotes for attributes, not single quotes

Comment: @ben [That's incorrect](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0). Attribute values can be surrounded by double, single, or even *no* quotes.

Comment: oh boy, you're right... however, what a mess it can be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes in the php, so it generates invalid HTML

```
echo '<td style="background: url(' . $row['thumbnails'] . ')" onclick="zoom(\'' . $row['imagelink'] . '\')"></td>';
```

Comment: Can you give more details ? a php syntax error, a js syntax error ? what does the error says exactly ?

Comment: I did it, it works, Thank you very much! there was syntax error was my fault. your answer is correct! thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume the $row['imagelink'] variable contains a filename string, eg 'file.jpeg'.
When echoed in PHP, the HTML onclick attribute would be

The quotes around file.jpeg are missing, so the PHP should be:

```
"<td style='background: url(" . $row['thumbnails'] . ")' onclick='zoom(\"" . $row['imagelink'] . "\")'></td>";
```